# How to make bootstrap navbar translucent when not scrolling and not transparent when scrolling?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, navbar

I just want my bootstrap nav bar to be in the translucent green color background when a user is not scrolling and when they start scrolling navbar needs to be solid green (no translucent). Any suggestion on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by scrolling? When the page is not at the top of the window or when you are moving the scroll cursor?

In both case you can detect it with javascript and add or remove a class on the navbar with the correct background color.